# Rename files in a folder?

Tags: python, file, rename

I'm learning how to code on Python 2.7.13 and I'm loving it! However, I'm stuck and wanted to seek your help.

I'm following off this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMw5EzdIucE

The task is to rename files in a folder, so that each file title has no numbers in them.

Here's my code that doesn't work:

```
import os

# step 1) find files in folder
for file in os.listdir("/Users/applereciate/Downloads/prank"):
    filelist = print(file)
    os.chdir("/Users/applereciate/Downloads/prank")

# step 2) for each file, rename filename 
    os.rename(filelist, filelist.translate(None, "0123456789"))
```

Here's the instructor's code, that also doesn't work for me:

```
import os
def rename_files(): 
#question 1: is it really necessary to define a function to solve this problem? 

    # step 1) find files in folder
    file_list = os.listdir("/Users/applereciate/Downloads/prank"):
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print("current working directory is "+saved_path)
    os.chdir("/Users/applereciate/Downloads/prank")

    # step 2) for each file, rename filename
    for file_name in file_list: 
#question 2: does this line make filename a file in filelist? so that it assumes that all files in filelist are now under the variable "filename"?
           os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789")) 
    os.chdir(saved_path)
    renamefiles()
#question 3: what's the purpose of this line above?
```

I'm keen to learn about why my code didn't work, so feel free to give me your honest thoughts.

Comment: `filelist = print(file)` huh ? do you have the image _and_ the sound on your video? :)

Comment: `print` prints the file name and returns `None`, so you end up trying to do `os.rename(None, None.translate(None, "0123456789"))`. Do `os.rename(file,filelist.translate(file, "0123456789"))` instead. As an aside, you end up in the target diretory... not the original directory.

Comment: If you are new to Python, why are you starting with Python 2? The [Stack Overflow Python community](http://sopython.com) overwhelmingly [recommends](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) starting with Python 3, as does [python.org itself](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3). Version 3 is the present and future of the language, while 2 is the past. In learning 2 first, you'll pick up many bad habits that will need to be corrected when you learn 3 (which you'll need to do eventually), so it's much better to start with 3 first, then learn the differences in 2 later.

Answer (score 0):

The file name is in `file`, so use it:

```
os.rename(file, file.translate(None, "0123456789"))
```

But if you really want to out do your instructor, skip chdir completely and consider the edge conditions.

```
import os
import re

basedir = "/Users/applereciate/Downloads/prank"

# does this directory exist?
if os.path.isdir(basedir):
    for fn in os.listdir(basedir):
        # Note: There are several ways to remove digits:
        # python 2.x
        # newfn = fn.translate(None, "0123456789")
        # python 3.x (but make trans outside the loop...)
        # trans = {ord(c):None for c in '0123456789'}
        # newfn = fn.translate(trans)
        # something that works in 2 and 3
        newfn = re.sub(r'\d+', '', fn)
        # don't bother with a rename if there wasnt a translation
        if newfn != fn:
            # don't chdir, just set your paths up right
            absfrom = os.path.join(basedir, fn)
            absto = os.path.join(basedir, newfn)
            # ignore subdirectories
            if os.isfile(absfrom):
                # see if we are overwriting anything
                if os.path.exists(absto):
                    print('ERROR: Name collision', absto)
                else:
                    os.rename(absfrom, absto)
```

Comment: Hi tdelaney, thanks for your response! That code you suggested looks crazy! I'm not entirely sure how to read it, but it's definitely something I would like to understand one day.

Comment: I also tried adding your line of coding with "file" instead of "filelist" into my first code, but it didn't work unfortunately. I also deleted Python 3 and installed Python 2.7, because apparently it's a lot better in terms of translating functions.

Comment: In python 2 where strings are 1 byte ascii, `str.translate` builds a 256 byte table for its mapping. In python 2 where strings are unicode, the table would be too large so `translate` moved to using a `dict` instead. Python 3 is far better but sometimes that means harder. No worries though, because regular expression substitution works in both cases. I updated my answer with several examples of how to do it.